# hash::class returns fixnum, why not undefined?

Tags: ruby

```
hash::class
```

returns Fixnum, maybe i'm being daft, but i cannot see why this does not return "undefined local variable or method". Anyone care to enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `hash` is a method that returns a number, not a missing variable as you suspect.

Specifically, Ruby top-level is executing in context where `self` is a special object called `main`, which is of class `Object`. Thus, it has all the methods that `Object` has, including [`Object#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-hash).

Answer (score -2):

hash is a method in the Range class. It returns a Fixnum hash-code for the range. 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Range.html#method-i-hash

Comment: "Doctor, my husband is very sick, can you tell me what's wrong?" "It's probably histoplasmosis, which a beagle would contract by inhaling spores from contaminated soil." "My husband is not a beagle!!?" `Range` has `hash`. But so does *every other class in Ruby* aside from `BasicObject`, and OP did not mention `Range` anywhere.

Comment: that was just the only class I had noticed it in, but +1 for taking the time to write such a snarky response.

Comment: You're welcome. I find colourful analogies to be very didactical. +1 for having a sense of humour (or passive aggressiveness, can't really tell :P )